# Comment that appears deleted to user is not marked as deleted in mod tools

Tags: feature-request, comments, moderator-tools, deleted-answers

I recently wrote an answer on an SE site. Voting and comments got a bit heated and I posted a comment that was not "nice". It was on my own answer and had no mentions, so nobody got pinged. After ten seconds thinking about it, I deleted the whole answer. I was assuming the whole thing was gone (or only accessible to 10K privilege users) including all comments, because in my UI seeing the thread, it was this nice red box that you probably know. Deleted content.

Meanwhile, the comment itself was probably not marked "deleted" in the database. Because following the programming, it wasn't, the answer was.

This means that if a moderator were to pull up the list of all comments I posted in the mod tools, they'd see the comment as if it were still "live" on the post.

This leads to the fact that mods see my "offensive" comment as active, not deleted in their view... while I am perfectly happy having "deleted" it after 13 seconds.

**Please improve the mod tools** so that mods and I share the same view on content. If I delete something that basically lets the comment vanish, this should be clearly visible in the mod view. Some indication in the comments list that while the comment may be not deleted, its parent post is.

Comment: So just that I understand: If I have 10K on RPG can I still see that offensive comment?

Comment: When the answer is deleted, the commend isn't really deleted - if you undelete the answer, the comment will still be there.

Comment: @rene Well... yes, because I deleted the answer. Right now, no you cannot, because I asked a mod to delete the comment "even more" so it's not just "gone" but "really gone". I understand the DB logic behind it, with answer and comment being different entities with their respective states of deletion, but if it's marked red for me as 10K user in the UI, it should show the mods that this comment is no longer active.

Comment: @Mithrandir I know and understand the programming logic behind it. But my point is that somebody is holding a comment against me, that I tried to delete and that was shown as deleted to me in my UI... only to find out that the mod UI still shows it as active. Show the mod that this comment is no longer accessible to the regular user.

Comment: Moderators also see the deleted answers/questions with the same red-ish background as you do. If you didn't delete the comment, they will see it same way you see it. Really no idea what you are asking here.

Comment: The *comment* was not shown as deleted. The *answer* was shown as deleted. And if a mod/you/(20kers? don't remember) undeletes the answer, the comment is shown even to the regular user.

Comment: @Mithrandir I guess you don't get my point: **right now** the answer and all comments are deleted content. So **right now** the mods should not see any of those comments as "active". Should I undelete it, then sure, hold my accountable for what is **then** visible. But don't hold me accountable, for content that I have to assume is **not** visible.

Comment: Did any of you actually *read* the linked comment thread between the mod and me? I'm sorry I cannot describe this better, **I cannot see it**. It's supposed to be a part of the mod tools.

Comment: If you can't see the comments under your own answer it means **they are deleted**, and this whole feature request is pointless

Comment: Next time edit the comment in the 5 minute grace period to something nice, then delete the comment and then your answer. I do know that requires a bit of self-control but it pays off in the end, bot online and in real-life. This concludes my *be a better person tip of the day* ...

Comment: It looks like SevenSidedDie explained it all there; what else are you looking for?

Comment: @Mithrandir Yes, SSD explained it. And I am looking for a solution where we don't have to have this confusing conversation the next time. If a comment is marked red for me (for whatever reason) please make sure it's also marked red in that mod tool he's talking about. That's all I want. Make the mod UI show the same information the user UI has.

Comment: (speaking as someone with access to mod tools) ...why? If the *comment* is not deleted, then **don't** show it as deleted.

Comment: @Mithrandir Would you please look at the picture I posted? It **is** deleted as far as a regular UI user can tell. It's red. It's not visible. I don't want to have to delete content that is already shown as deleted to me *again* to make mod-tools happy.

Comment: I did look at the picture. And those comments are not deleted. [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wvTSC.png) is what deleted comments look like.

Comment: Those comments having a "red background" is a consequence of being attached to a deleted post. They are not deleted; at least not in the way that comments are deleted. Site moderators can see specifically-deleted comments, as well. But that's pretty much beside the point. (Also, you don't seem to be concerned about _your_ ability to read the comments by Clarus_Nox and mxyzplk in that picture. You're not even a site moderator and you can read others' "deleted" comments!)

Comment: What's the actual problem here?

Comment: @Cai the actual problem is that a comment that was shown as "red" to me because I deleted the *whole answer* it sat on, is still displayed as active in the mod tools and therefor held against me, even if I deleted the whole conversation.

Comment: What do you mean by "held against you"?

Comment: Used by a mod to suspend my account. Please do not go into the details, this is **not** about the suspension. This is about the fact that a mod told me that certain information is not visible in his tools and I request that it be made visible. I'm really at a loss what the problem with giving the mods more information in their tool could be. Why would anybody say "no, do not give this information in the mod tools".

Comment: @AdamLear Maybe you can explain **why** you declined the request? Maybe I misunderstood something and it's actually there? Is it too much work for too little gain? "Declined" without feedback feels very unprofessional.

Comment: @nvoigt Sure. We're not going to be making changes to how deleted content behaves at this time. The answer is deleted, the comments are not. There's no "mod tool" involved here beyond the ability to view deleted answers in their state at deletion - including the comment discussions - and that's entirely intentional. Adding extra notation would clutter the view while not adding much in the way of new information. If you prefer, I can re-tag as status-bydesign.

Comment: @AdamLear ok, now I'm really confused. You say there is no such thing in the mod tools. Yet my mod tells me [`It's on your record in the mod tools as a non-deleted comment`](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7030/how-to-give-feedback-that-is-not-in-line-with-mod-opinion-without-getting-tempor#comment21747_7031). My request just is to *show* in that ominous mod-tool that the comment is non-deleted, *but still not visible to the general public* because it's on a deleted answer. I don't want you to change any behavior, I just want that information be shown.

Comment: @nvoigt Oh, sorry - I was referring to the post view itself. My bad. I misunderstood what you were going for, then. In *that* tool... yeah, that sounds like a decent idea. I'm not 100% sure it's easily doable (we don't query the posts in that view, just the comments), but it's worth exploring.

Comment: @AdamLear ok, thanks for looking into it. My case seems to be a pretty weird case when looking at how many people misunderstood me here, but maybe you can fit it in when you work on it for other reasons anyway.

Comment: @nvoigt I'm gonna attempt an edit to your post here to describe what you're requesting in more direct terms. :)

Comment: @AdamLear You're very welcome, as I said, I'm kinda navigating in the dark here, describing a feature in a tool I've never seen.

Comment: This makes more sense now. I've retracted my unclear vote, reversed my downvote, and deleted my answer. So this is on the comments view, which currently shows no context about the post from which the comments came (in particular, whether the post itself was deleted), hence the issue. Right? cc @AdamLear

Comment: For reference, the mod tool output looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7svt.png. (cc @JasonC)

Comment: Well that was quite the turnaround. There's got to be a badge or a hat in here somewhere...

Comment: nvoigt, while I'm happy you like my answer, SE might see a feature request with an accepted answer as "done; nothing for us to do here" so maybe you don't want to do that. @AdamLear, I tried to suggest a low-impact implementation in my answer.

Comment: @MonicaCellio Hm, maybe you are right, I'll leave it open then, thank you.

Answer (score 7):

As a moderator I've been tripped up by this too.  It would be really helpful if the "all comments from this user" view in the mod tools could indicate somehow that a comment, while not *deleted*, is nonetheless not *visible*.  Since we also get the post ID, it'd be sufficient to decorate *that* somehow (e.g. red background), which avoids having to come up with a way to represent a third comment state.  (Also, this might be easier than doing something to individual comments.)

When mods notice a pattern of inappropriate comments from a user, we use that page to see what else might need to be cleaned up.  That's one of the reasons that page *exists*.  When we see something in that list of comments that looks problematic we need to go to the page to see if it's on a live or deleted post -- not ideal for users with lots of comments.  (And on some sites, *boy* do people like to post lots of comments!)